# $\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2} \in \mathbb{R}$. Is my solution correct? Why?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to show that if numbers:

- $z_1$ and $z_2 \in \mathbb{C} $
- $ |z_1| = |z_2| = 1 $
- $z_1*z_2 \neq -1$

then:
$$\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2} \in \mathbb{R}$$

So I thought I can transform that expression like that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}
&= \frac{(z_1+z_2)(1-z_1z_2)}{(1+z_1z_2)(1-z_1z_2)}
= \frac{z_1-z_1*z_1z_2+z_2-z_2*z_1z_2}{|1+z_1z_2|^2}
\\
&= \frac{z_1-|z_1|^2*z_2+z_2-|z_2|^2*z_1}{|1+z_1z_2|^2}
\\
&= \frac{z_1-z_2+z_2-z_1}{|1+z_1z_2|^2} = \frac{0}{|1+z_1z_2|^2}
\\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Is that correct? Could you tell me exactly why $(1+z_1z_2)(1-z_1z_2) = |1+z_1z_2|^2$ ?

I know that $z * \bar z = |z|^2$. But that equality gets me confused (if it is even right).

Comment: You have “proved” that $\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2} = 0$. That cannot be correct.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787670/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2939910/42969 for various correct solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct: $$(1+z_1z_2)(1-z_1z_2)=|1+z_1z_2|^2$$

it should be $$(1+z_1z_2)(\overline {1+z_1z_2})=|1+z_1z_2|^2$$

as $|w|^2 =w\cdot \overline{w}$. (Notice further that $\overline {1+z_1z_2} = \overline{1}+\overline {z_1z_2} =1 + \overline {z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2})$

Also, you could easyl check it is not correct if you take $z_1=z_2=1$, you don't get $0$ at the end.

Comment: maybe you can mention that $(1+ \overline{z_1 z_2}) = \overline{(1+ z_1 z_2)}$ (linearity).

Comment: I have given another solution with a geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

Since @Aqua has  resolved your query here ia  an alternate proof$$\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}=\frac{\frac{1}{\bar {z_1}}+\frac{1}{\bar {z_2}}}{1+\frac{1}{\bar {z_1}\bar{z_2}}}=\frac{\bar z_1+\bar z_2}{1+\bar z_1\bar z_2}$$

As $X=\bar X \Rightarrow X$ is real  we complete the proof

Comment: Interesting, people don't even answer the question asked and get upvoted.

Comment: @Aqua seeing that you have answwresd the OP's query i thought i could provide an alternate proof

Comment: It is not you I'm talking about, I'm talking about upvoters.

Comment: @Aqua i dont  understand do you mean to say that this anwer is not worth upvoting

Comment: No, I did not say that.

Comment: @Aqua please tell me then your intent,

Comment: You solved the problem (nicely), but that is not the question.

Comment: @Albus, your answer is not what OP really asked for. You may begin your answer like "Here is an alternative proof". Without any such mention, I guess some readers get confused.

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you for mentioning so i have edited

Comment: Very nice, @Albus!

Comment: @Aqua okay i got your point your it took me a lot of time to grasp your comments.I will  make sure i  say its an alternative proof before jumping to the answer next time.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add a geometric interpretation explaining this property:

**if $z_1 \ne z_2$, $z=z_3=\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}$ is the intersection of line $[z_1,z_2]$ with the real axis.**

[image]

Indeed, line $[z_1,z_2]$ has equation:

$$\begin{vmatrix}z_1&\overline{z_1}&1\\
z_2&\overline{z_2}&1\\
z&\overline{z}&1
\end{vmatrix}=0 \tag{1}$$

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2111593)).

As we are looking for a real $z$, we have $\overline{z}=z$.

Taking into account the fact that $\overline{z_1}=\tfrac{1}{z_1}$ and $\overline{z_2}=\tfrac{1}{z_2}$, it is not difficult, by multiplying by $z_1z_2$  to obtain by Laplace expansion of (1) followed by a factorization by $(z_2-z_1$):

$$(z_2-z_1)(z(1+z_1z_2)-(z_1+z_2))=0$$

$$\iff z_1=z_2 \ \ \text{or} \ \ z=\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}$$

as desired.

**Remark:** if $z_1=z_2$, by continuity, point $z$ is the intersection point of the tangent to the unit circle with the real axis.

Comment: Perhaps if you poste it here it would be more appropriate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787670/proving-a-complex-number-is-real or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939910/question-about-proving-that-a-fraction-of-complex-numbers-is-real

Comment: @Aqua I understand your point. I will say for my defence that you had already answered by spotting the error; I wanted to give the whole answer, as Albus Dumbledore has one as well, with a different flavor, a geometric one...

Comment: Ok course....+1